# Execute MySQL script in grails app

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0, sql-scripts

I have an MySQL Script I want to execute in a controller when my `Grails 3.0.9` application is running. I've tried it this way:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import grails.util.Holders

    def void clearDatabase() {
        String sqlFilePath = 'path/to/file/clear_database.sql'
        String sqlString = new File(sqlFilePath).text
        def sql = Sql.newInstance(Holders.config.dataSource.url, Holders.config.dataSource.username, Holders.config.dataSource.password, Holders.config.dataSource.driverClassName)
        sql.execute(sqlString)
    }
```

Thats how my `clear_database.sql` file looks like:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE table_a;
TRUNCATE table_b;
TRUNCATE table_c;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Thats the error message I get:

```
WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Warning Code: 1064, SQLState: 42000
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRUNCATE table_a;
```

Is my MySQL syntax wrong or am I missing something else?

**edit:**

When I run the script manually it works. So I think the script is correct but the way I execute it not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `sql.execute(sqlString)` wants a `GString` and I've given it a normal `String` so it added quotes and the result was an incorrect MySQL syntax like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411874/2514164).

That's how it works for me:

```
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(Holders.config.dataSource.url, Holders.config.dataSource.username, Holders.config.dataSource.password, Holders.config.dataSource.driverClassName)
    sql.execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"
    sql.execute "truncate ${Sql.expand("table_a")}"
    sql.execute "truncate ${Sql.expand("table_b")}"
    sql.execute "truncate ${Sql.expand("table_c")}"
    sql.execute "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"
```

There is no `clear_database.sql` file needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but could you try: as your  `clear_database.sql`

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
    TRUNCATE TABLE table_a;
    TRUNCATE TABLE table_b;
    TRUNCATE TABLE table_c;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Good luck!!